# How to set total_timesteps in Stable-Baseline, model.learn() function?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I'm using Stable-Baseline to train A2C model.

My data length is 9000. So how many `total_timesteps` in `model.learn` should I set?

```
model.learn(total_timesteps = 9000) # ?
```

I did some research and some suggest like 10000, and some suggest 1 million. I'm really confused.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reinforcement-learning/info . Also, why both `pytorch` and `tensorflow` tags?

Answer (score 0):

The total_timesteps in Stable-Baseline is the total number of samples (env steps) to train on. So it should not be necessary the same as the length of the episode you have.

Comment: Please explain your answer